# Print HTML with header and footer every page on all browser

Tags: css

header at top of each


    several pages...


Footer at the bottom of each page with page no

I want to print #header and #footer with page no on every page in HTML print mode. However I'd try CSS @media print @page @bottom-center @top-center. But it doesn't work.

Comment: yeah you can't repeat content with html and css - you need a backend-language like php (this might not be 100% true - could be some weird framework out there to achieve with just html and css)

Comment: I agree with @ThisGuy, if you use PHP you can simply `require 'header.php';` and `require 'footer.php';` or use of Laravel means you can use `@extends('page.header')` etc.. depends on what framework you're using etc.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can use:

```
<link rel="import" href="http://example.com/elements.html">
```

But in real life this HTML tag work only on modern browser and this is not good idea to use this option.

Better is to use PHP language and `<?php require '...'; ?>`

Comment: I use grails app and javascript, besides PHP any suggestion?